# How to reproduce a timeout error with ASP.NET web API app and IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-web-api, timeout, iis-express

The whole idea is to reproduce the limitations the application has in production in my development environment (timeout, payload size, ...)

I made a fresh new ASP.NET web API app and modify a method controller to respond after 2 minutes wait.

```
// GET api/values
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    Thread.Sleep(120000);
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Then I changed the IIS Express config file `$(solutionDir)\.vs\MyWebApi\config\applicationhost.config` to add a timeout of 1 minute:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <asp>
      <session timeout="00:01:00" />
    </asp>

  <!-- ... -->

  <location path="MyWebApi">
    <system.webServer>
      <asp>
        <session timeout="00:01:00" />
      </asp>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

No success, I did the same with the main IIS Express config file `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`: no success.
So I tried to modify my `web.config` file by adding a timeout of 1 minute:

```
  <system.webServer>
      <asp>
          <session timeout="00:01:00" />
      </asp>
```

Still without success.
Does anyone know how could I reproduce a timeout error with an ASP.NET web API app and IIS Express?

Comment: Not sure I follow this, but if you want to limit a API call, use cancellation tokens, do a search for cancellation tokens, you can set the token for a sensbile time and will produce a timeout error.

Comment: @Rav thanks for your comment. Using `CancellationTokenSource ` is a good idea, but I am looking for a way to configure my entire application in one place.